# How to exclude based on top-level dependencies for maven shade plugin?

Tags: maven, maven-shade-plugin

I have one dependency that I want to exclude from my fat jar and that dependency has lots of transitive dependencies. Is there some config I can set in my pom file so that that dependency and all its transitive dependencies are excludes from the fat jar without listing every single one of these dependencies?

Comment: Have you tried filtering the dependencies as mentioned here: http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/examples/includes-excludes.html ?

Comment: yes, but that requires me to go through the dependency hierarchy and exclude not only the top level dependencies and find all their transitive dependencies and exclude those as well. I want to know if there's a way to just specify the top level dependencies and exclude it and all its transitive dependencies as well.

Comment: Just give a try for `<minimizeJar>true</minimizeJar>` – it will do the dirty job for you.